# Push data from php web application to C# windows form application

Tags: c#, php, .net, web-services

I have a server client application. Server is developed in php and client is in C# windows forms On server i assign some task to the clients registered on it. On client side i have some 60 seconds interval after which my client connects to server and ask for task that client has to perform. Currently i am using WSDL SOAP to do this on my server side i.e in php and my clients calls this webservice in every 60 sec. Now i want to use push technology so that when user assigns task for client server will push the xml string to client.

I googled a lot but not found anything where php can push content to c# desktop application.
Can someone guide me?

Comment: How much control do you have over the clients?  Can you send a connection from the server to the client directly?

Comment: server haave all the access to clients. It knows the IP of each client and connect it anytime as there is no problem of firewall, nat etc

Comment: Is there any reason you can't pull the data from the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to code the clients to accept information from the server. They will need to be accessible on the network from the server. On the PHP/server side, there are a number of ways to connect to other networked entities: sockets, cURL, etc.